# I want to Adding items to a cart on quantity change with WooCommerce

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I am building an eCommerce website using WooCommerce. On the product page, in addition to the specific product, I have optional addons with quantity buttons beneath them to add to the cart.

I am trying to get these items to add to the cart every time the quantity is changers (i.e when someone hits the plus sign, it automatically adds the corresponding item to the cart).ideally whichever item I hit the plus sign for is the only item I want added to the cart.
[image1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/T8MZi.jpg)

[image2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9fclO.jpg)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to [this documentation](https://woocommerce.github.io/code-reference/files/woocommerce-includes-class-wc-cart.html#source-view.1368), you can use a [wordpress action](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/do_action/)

the hook name is called woocommerce_cart_item_set_quantity and you can use it like this

```php
function custom_plugin_callback( $cart_item_key,$quantity,$cart_object) {
    // (maybe) do something with the args.

// Add another item
    $cart_object->add_to_cart( $product_id = 0, $quantity = 1, $variation_id = 0, $variation = array(), $cart_item_data = array() )

}
add_action( 'woocommerce_cart_item_set_quantity ', 'custom_plugin_callback', null, 3  );
```

Here, custom_plugin_callback() function would be called each time an item has his quantity updated, with the quantity and the cart id of the item

Many other cart actions are available in the .php sources files linked in [this page](https://woocommerce.github.io/code-reference/classes/WC-Cart.html#method_set_quantity)  Each of them can provide useful callbacks ( Check do_action() calls to get the hooks names )